# How to loop through all JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I'm trying to add multiple Objects and later to display them all. How would I do this? Every method I googled just uses For-In/For and iterate through characters and I only see the last added object...

```
for(var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) 
{
        alert(forms[i].id + " " + 10 + " " + forms[i].value);
        var aObj = new A(forms[i].id, 10, forms[i].value);
        var obj = JSON.stringify(aObj);
}

var str = "";
for(var i = 0; i < jObj.length; i++) 
{
    str += jObj[i]; 
}

alert(str);
```

Only solution I can come up is to create an array and store them all there?

Comment: I don't see where you're adding the object into the jObj array. Can you show that as well?

Comment: I misunderstood your question, HelpNeeder. See edit.

Comment: Although you aren't adding them to an array in your code (like @Joel already noted), there's nothing wrong in storind them in an array (i.e. with `obj[i]` in your code above, just declare obj as an Array outside the first loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reinitalizing the variables `aObj` and `obj` and that is causing them to be overwritten every time the loop is executed. They should be arrays with the iteration specified.

```
var aObj;
var obj = [];
var str = "";

for(var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) 
{
        alert(forms[i].id + " " + 10 + " " + forms[i].value);
        aObj = new A(forms[i].id, 10, forms[i].value);
        obj[i] = JSON.stringify(aObj);
}

for(var i = 0; i < jObj.length; i++) 
{
    str += jObj[i]; 
}

alert(str);
```

Comment: Ok, so array is its. Ok, but I don't think aObj[] need to be an array.

Comment: aObj refers to A (non-default) constructor.

Comment: @HelpNeeder you are right, revised. Btw, what is `jObj` in the second loop? Did you mean `obj`?

Comment: Thats a JSON object which result in stringified output, so I thought. Your answer helps a lot. Thanks.